# splitting values in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have this data frame in R.
name of df: POST

```
Order_id Postcalcode
1        5253HP
2        4261FF
44       5111QW
```

I want to split the numbers and the letters from the postal code because i only need  the numbers so expected output is

```
Order_id Postalcode
1        5253
2        4261
44       5111
```

Comment: `gsub("\\D", "", df$Postalcode)` in base R

Comment: just a clarification, here you do not need the rstudio tag but rather just the r tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(Postcalcode = str_extract(Postcalcode,"\\d+"))

  Order_id Postcalcode
1        1        5253
2        2        4261
3       44        5111
```

Comment: Do I need a library or something? I get ``` could not find function "str_extract" ```

Comment: I have dyplr for %>%

Comment: stringr::str_extract() comes from the stringr package

Comment: my apologies. Have updated with packages

Answer (score 1):

Also, [`tidyr::separate`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) may be worth looking at. In the example below the split is taking place at the defined position.

```
dta <- readr::read_table(file = "
Order_id Postcalcode
1        5253HP
2        4261FF
44       5111QW")

tidyr::separate(
    data = dta,
    col = "Postcalcode",
    into = c("first_part", "second_part"),
    sep = 4,
    remove = FALSE
)
```

*Results:*

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Order_id Postcalcode first_part second_part
     <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      
1        1 5253HP      5253       HP         
2        2 4261FF      4261       FF         
3       44 5111QW      5111       QW
```